# Requested url "localhost/ecommerce/admin_area" not found on this server

Tags: php

I am creating one website using php and mysql. But now I want to insert a product, when I insert the product using this url `localost/ecommerce/admin_area/insert_product.php` I get this error:

> **Object not found!**
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14

What could be the solution for this problem?

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inserting Product</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table align="center" width="1000">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h2>Insert New Post Here</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide screenshots of error with url and your working directory

Answer (score 0):

if localhost is not working then try 127.0.0.1

```
http://127.0.0.1/ecommerce/admin_area/insert_product.php
```

and see if insert_product.php has 755 permission

Comment: hai sir. it is also same problem.. ow to solve the probllem pls help me

Comment: options :1. instead of clicking on a click go directlly to browser and access pathname/insert_product.php 2. check the filename 3. change the filename

Comment: sir can u send ur mail id. if i got any problem i will mail u

Comment: Actually if it works you have to select it as the right answer so if anyone have the same problem find it useful